# Unit testing: getText is not a function

Tags: mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I'm new to unit testing and I'm trying to select an ID to select its text and check if it equals 'Inbox'. I'm getting a

> TypeError in "User visits Quick Add Task starts with a blank task" elem.getText is not a function

and I don't understand why.
Test source code [here](https://pastebin.com/77qUEnpB).

```
describe('User visits Quick Add Task', () => {
    it('starts with a blank task', () => {
        browser.url('http://localhost:8080/');

        const elem = $('#inbox-clickable');
        console.log(elem.getText());

        assert.equal(elem.getText(), 'Inbox');

    })
});
```

Comment: Hi, Have you tried adding a `wait` after `browser.url`? Just want to make sure the `elem` has value on it. You can also check the WDIO logs to see when `$('#inbox-clickable')` returned an element.

Comment: @NaveenThiyagarajan: I've realized I should have probably pasted my terminal output: https://pastebin.com/FgbxWYP3

Comment: I added 'elem.waitForDisplayed(3000);' after the 'elem' declaration. Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Hi.. Might be we can go step by step. Can you verify by adding a hard pause immediately after `browser.url`.

Comment: I added browser.pause(5000);  after browser.url. Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/cFw8Vp3C

Comment: Hey, based on the logs, i have a feeling that the commands are running async manner. Can you confirm whether Sync is turned on for your test?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Sync is turned on, since I've followed the configuration instructions on the website. Although I can't seem to be able to confirm it. I've looked for it in 'wdio.conf.js' but there's nothing there. Where can I get that info?

Comment: Which configuration instructions did you follow? Maybe you can list your setup process in the question?

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution to a very similar problem was adding the missing `@wdio/sync` package to my `package.json`.

I already had previously added `sync: true,` to my `wdio.conf.js` and remove all `async` and `await` from my testing code.